# python - create new sub-matrix by filtering columns from matrix/bidimensional list

Tags: python, matrix, filtering

for instance the following a matrix, e.g.

```
matrix = [
    ['month','val1','val2','valn'],
    ['jan','100','200','300'],
    ['feb','101',201',302'],
    ['march','102','202','303'],
    ['april','103','203','303'],
    ['march','104','204','304']
]
```

I'd like to create a new matrix based on a list of columns indexes or names (filter in), so

```
filter_col_indx = {0,2}
filter_col_name = {'month','val2'}
```

would produce the same output:

```
matrix2 = [
    ['month,'val2'],
    ['jan','200'],
    ['feb','201'],
    ['march','202'],
    ['april','203'],
    ['march','204']
]
```

For large matrices what would be the most efficient way to do this? The list_of_columns can vary.

Thanks

Comment: I would check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).  You could subset your data using two lines `df = pd.DataFrame(matrix[1:], columns=matrix[0])
df[['month', 'val2']]`

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
import operator
matrix = [
    ['month','val1','val2','valn'],
    ['jan','100','200','300'],
    ['feb','101','201','302'],
    ['march','102','202','303'],
    ['april','103','203','303'],
    ['march','104','204','304']
]

filter_col_indx = [0,2]
getter = operator.itemgetter(*filter_col_indx)
matrix2 = [list(getter(row)) for row in matrix]
print(matrix2)
```

yields

```
[['month', 'val2'],
 ['jan', '200'],
 ['feb', '201'],
 ['march', '202'],
 ['april', '203'],
 ['march', '204']]
```

---

`operator.itemgetter(*filter_col_indx)` returns a function which takes a sequence as its argument and returns the 0th and 2th items from the sequence. Thus, you can apply this function to each row to select the desired values from `matrix`.

---

If you install [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), then you could make `matrix` a DataFrame and select the desired columns like this:

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = [
    ['month','val1','val2','valn'],
    ['jan','100','200','300'],
    ['feb','101','201','302'],
    ['march','102','202','303'],
    ['april','103','203','303'],
    ['march','104','204','304']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix[1:], columns=matrix[0])
print(df[['month', 'val2']])
```

yields

```
   month val2
0    jan  200
1    feb  201
2  march  202
3  april  203
4  march  204
```

You might enjoy using pandas since it make a lot of data-munging operations very easy.

Comment: Thanks for such nice examples. One small issue, the example using  _operator.itemgetter_ produces a list of tuples and not a list of lists. Is there a way to convert it back to the desired format: [ ['month' 'val2'],
     ['jan' '200'] ... ] ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're always interested in whole columns, I think it would be appropriate to store the data using a dictionary containing the columns as lists:

```
data = {'month': ['jan', 'feb', 'march', 'april', 'march'],
        'val1': [100, 101, 102, 103, 104],
        'val2': [200, 201, 202, 203, 204],
        ...
       }
```

To retrieve columns (which I have now written horizontally...), you do:

```
{key: data[key] for key in ['month', 'val2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a numpy version for this:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([
    ['month','val1','val2','valn'],
    ['jan','100','200','300'],
    ['feb','101','201','302'],
    ['march','102','202','303'],
    ['april','103','203','303'],
    ['march','104','204','304']
])

search = ['month', 'val2']

indexes = matrix[0,:].searchsorted(search) #search only the first row
# or indexes = [0, 2]
print matrix[:,indexes] 
>>> [['month' 'val2']
     ['jan' '200']
     ['feb' '201']
     ['march' '202']
     ['april' '203']
     ['march' '204']]
```